# How i get the pc name, ip and mac addres with php or javascript?

Tags: php, ip-address, mac-address

I'm asking if there is a way to get the name, ip and mac of a pc with php or javacript?

I need this to configure a view in an application I developed. In this case, the user uses windows to access my application that is built with the PHP framework, codeignter, and obviously I use PHP to connect with the DB.

Why the name of the PC? Well ! the name of the pc in a network can be replaced with another pc with the same name. With the mac address can't. but its a way i cant get the name, ip and mac of a pc who acces to my aplication i want to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting the MAC address isn't possible without some browser plugin client-side.

Also, you should know that it is very easy to change your MAC address.  Besides, not everyone even has one.  Ethernet is not a prerequisite for internet access.

You can get the remote address out of `$_SERVER` data in PHP, but it isn't always the real client IP, in cases of proxying or NAT.

Answer (score 1):

Impossible with just PHP, JavaScript, and nothing else.

You can get the IP address though, with `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`. Note that if the user uses some kind of IP-hiding software like Hide My IP or such, this won't work either.

For the PC Name and Mac address, as Brad has mentioned, you need a client-side plugin, with another programming language, most likely Java or Flash.

Answer (score 0):

Using PHP, you can't get information about the computer specifically, unless it has been input into a form or something like that.

However, if you go to this question, you will find how to learn the name using Javascript.

[How can I read the client's machine/computer name from the browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922476/how-can-i-read-the-clients-machine-computer-name-from-the-browser)

Answer (score 0):

To get the real IP address you can use this code

```
<?php
//whether ip is from share internet
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))   
  {
    $ip_address = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
  }
//whether ip is from proxy
elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))  
  {
    $ip_address = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
  }
//whether ip is from remote address
else
  {
    $ip_address = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
  }
echo $ip_address;
?>
```