# There is any possible way to get visitor computer name?

Tags: php

for the security purpose how I get visitor computer name and related details using php?

I try `$_ENV['COMPUTERNAME']` it showing my server name not client computer details...

There is any option to get client computer name?

Comment: on intranet you could do reverse dns

Comment: You can't get someone else's computer name. Their browser **does not supply that data** by default. You can only obtain what the browser sends to the server.

Comment: What is the relation between the name of a computer and security?

Comment: how to find from which computer the user accesss my website

Comment: "for the security purpose" this info is not accessible to a web server unless the user wants to provide it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/922476/how-can-i-read-the-clients-machine-computer-name-from-the-browser

Comment: or there is any other way to get country and latitude of the ip address he access? in php?

Comment: [Does this give you what you want?](http://php.net/manual/en/function.geoip-record-by-name.php)

Answer (score 2):

In normal cases, you can't. The only things you can retrieve are:

- the data sent with the request from the browser and/or
- the server info.

Sending the computer name as part of the request simply doesn't make sense for the browser. Also, I'm skeptical it is even possible (in a reliable way) to get it via *other ways*.

Answer (score -1):

```
echo 'Current computer  owner: ' . get_current_user().'</br>';
```

I have only found this code that returns the name you have given to the computer Soory i think is error return the carrent owner of http protocol to have the php online page  and works on the online server at local server youcan have your machine name with

```
echo 'Computer Name: ' . getenv('COMPUTERNAME').'</br>';
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. If you are going to add an answer a 10 year old question, it should be a correct and complete one. Nevemind the issues with the question itself!

Comment: sorry, I'm looking for the same topic after 10 years, it would help if I had an answer, but I only found codes that found the name of the client only on the local server, the name of the online server and an ip address that can change from each machine, I probably don't have one answer if we can find out the name of the one you are visiting us with.