# Pass Javascript variable to servlet doGet method

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, servlets, web

I have a javascript function to retrieve the users workstation like the one here.
[How can I read the client's machine/computer name from the browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922476/how-can-i-read-the-clients-machine-computer-name-from-the-browser)

My question is, how can I pass the computername (result from the function) to the servlets doGet() method?

Currently my code (snippet) that calls the servlet is as follows:

```
    <html>
    <head> .... <script> load my javascript file here </script></head>
    <%
      if(session.getAttribute("Login") == null){
         //I want to pass the computer name here
         response.sendRedirect("../LOGME");
      } else {
        //draw page body
      } %>
     </html>
```

Comment: how are you calling servlet? just pass it as query params. `setletPath?computerName=xyz`

Comment: I'm using response.sendRedirect(redirectURL);

Comment: so do you call it on button/hyperlink click?

Comment: @GoAlves It depends where did you use it. Currently as it has written it's difficult to tell you about it. Please clarify the question with details.

Comment: Hi! I have edited my question with a code snippet to better illustrate the topic.
Thanks!

Comment: @Braj I don't have any buttons. The page gets redirected automatically if the Login attribute is null when the user opens the page.

Answer (score 0):

Let the client redirect.

```
<%
  if(session.getAttribute("Login") == null){ %>
     <script>
         location.href = "../LOGME?name=" + yourValue;
     </script>
 <% return; // you should check the return ...
  } else {
    //draw page body
  } %>
```

Won't work on my machine though. I'm on Linux, so no f... ActiveX.