# Getting client environment variable value from java

Tags: javascript, java

I have a web project, and I try to get the environment variable value from the client by Java. I use

```
System.getenv("computername");
```

but it always return the computername of server, so how can I get the environment variable value from client in java or javascript ?

Comment: you can't using java .you should use client language like `javascript` .but i think it's impossible .read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/922476/how-can-i-read-the-clients-machine-computer-name-from-the-browser

Comment: you need to do that in your javascript, i hope java runs on your server while javascript runs on your browser

Comment: I think you are getting server side and client side development mixed up.  _Where_ do you need to use the client side computer name?

Comment: yes, I think I should use it in javascript, but I cannot find any solution for it :(

Comment: @user3040408 because it's impossible.read the question i have linked there is answers but only work for ie

Comment: For security reasons you can not do it even using Javascript.  if you asked the user to fill in the field then you could pass it as a parameter.

Comment: thanks for all answer :D, so could I get the computer name from client's IP Address ?

Comment: ip address can be changed [dynamic ip] .

Comment: this no problem @FastSnail because I will get IP Address when login and then get Env value and keep it in session :D

Comment: @user3040408 you can't get computer name even throw ip address .why do you want to get computer name??

Answer (score 0):

I think its possible if you use applets on client side.Am not sure javascript on client side can provide environment info.