# How to get computer name using javascript WScript.Network?

Tags: javascript

Example:

```
<script type = "text/JavaScript">
try
{
var ax = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Network");
document.write('User: ' + ax.UserName + '<br />');
document.write('Computer: ' + ax.ComputerName + '<br />');
}
catch (e)
{
document.write('Permission to access computer name is denied' + '<br />');
}
</Script>
```

Actually I am Getting the Following output:

> Permission to access computer name is denied

Please help to get Client Machine Computer name using jquery / Javascript (Php).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is explained in the following [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922476/how-can-i-read-the-clients-machine-computer-name-from-the-browser). They say it is (in most cases) impossible to do.

However, if you are making an internal application you can 'register' each computer to a database and save the computername and IP. And then you can later use the IP of the host to determine the hostname by querying it to the database.

Comment: is this possible to change any settings in  each system to access computer name......

Comment: Its will only work on older IE. Add your domian to the Tools -> Internet Options -> Security tab -> Trusted sites Zone -> Sites.  ref [link](https://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/92507-get-computer-name)

Answer (score 3):

ActiveX is a Microsoft-proprietary framework.Your code works only in IE.
In other browsers ActiveXObject really does not exist. You will get an error like this,

> Uncaught ReferenceError: ActiveXObject is not defined

Answer (score 2):

```
  var network = new ActiveXObject('WScript.Network');
        // Show a pop up if it works
        alert(network.computerName);
```