# How to access hostname from the browser similar to how Google Accounts does it?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webrtc

Google Accounts seem to be able to access that information just by having access to my browser (Chrome): 
[image: Google Accounts shows computer hostname]

I assume this can be done through WebRTC. There wasn't any prompt to access my network, but probably hostname can be read without it.

What API that uses?

Comment: navigator.userAgent

Comment: With WebRTC (PeerConnection API) you can only get local(LAN) IP,  not the host name.

Comment: Interesting. There must be some way how google does it, how else apart from browser api would it get that information out of session. I haven't got any desktop google software running.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I read the client's machine/computer name from the browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922476/how-can-i-read-the-clients-machine-computer-name-from-the-browser)

Comment: That question and not any of it answers address chrome though... Thinking about it now, it must be coming from chrome extensions or the chrome sync. Wonder whether they provide an api to use for web devs.

Comment: The google software that was installed on my mac was Google Chrome all along...

Comment: Thanks. Sorry I couldn't give a more helpful answer. Chrome is always going to be more powerful than Chrome extensions, because it's a native app. It's probably calling the OS-level APIs (e.g., https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724295(v=vs.85).aspx… on Windows). But that kind of information wouldn't be provided via the extensions API for the reasons. Hopefully that make sense