# Get client name in google chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

How is it possible to get the clients computer name via javascript in the chrome browser?
Using the IE it is possible using ActiveX

```
var network = new ActiveXObject('WScript.Network');
var clientName = network.computerName;
```

Is there a way to achive this in google chrome without forcing the client to install any plugin?

Comment: I feel this is not duplicate. The answer in linked question is for IE. That will not work in Chrome as title says..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no possible solution to get the computer name without using ActiveX in all browsers.
Nevertheless, this question is a duplicate of [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922476/how-can-i-read-the-clients-machine-computer-name-from-the-browser)

PS: Never use ActiveX unless you can avoid it!

Comment: For that matter, Microsoft no longer support ActiveX in current browsers and Windows 10.