# How to get unique id of a device that is navigating in my website

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to do subscription by device,
I've placed a subscription button on my website to send notifications to those who have subscribed.

therefore I need to retrieve the users device's mac-address or unique id 
how do I do this? any help/guide would be very beneficial thanks in advance

Comment: What have you done so far to solve it? any tutorial link or code sample?

Comment: there are no tutorials or samples, so far I'm only able to get server mac-address, and send push notifications to myself

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I read the client's machine/computer name from the browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922476/how-can-i-read-the-clients-machine-computer-name-from-the-browser)

Comment: Well HttpRequest Server Variables key HTTP_USER_AGENT can only provide some info if not all. Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_USER_AGENT"];

Comment: will look into these now

Comment: You won't be able to get the client's MAC address as that information isn't provided over the http protocol in normal way. It can be achive by ActiveX by this solution will only work in IE. 
Other option is to use cookies for this if you don't have member login/signup .
Also look into **FCM** and **Peer.js** may be you get better solution.