# Get device name php js

Tags: javascript, php

Is it possible to get the computer name in php or javascript?

if I use this function, it works correctly only locally

```
gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
```

Comment: Do you want the computer name or the IP address? For IP address, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634782/).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I read the client's machine/computer name from the browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922476/how-can-i-read-the-clients-machine-computer-name-from-the-browser)